# How to get a user to input text n times and store it in a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, user-input, prompt

I am writing code that is supposed to take user information and store it in a text file. I would like to know how I can get the user to input the information n times so that if I ask "Enter 5:" after they enter 5, the next prompt should be "Enter 4:" and so on until they exit the while loop.

This function will take, as an argument, a positive integer n, and create a file named nLinesOfText.txt, containing n lines of text obtained through keyboard input. The function should prompt the user to enter text n times, and it should write that information to file.

```
def userInput(n):
    fileName = "nLinesOfText.txt"
    outputFile = open(fileName, "w")
    counter = 0
    # make n positive
    n>0
    # use a while loop for when counter is less than n
    while (counter<n):
        # ask user to print n
        textPrint = input("Enter {}:".format(n))
        #convert the text to a string and write it the output File
        outputFile.write(str(textPrint) + "\n")
        # exit out of the loop when counter is equal to n
        counter = n+1
    # close the file
    outputFile.close()
```

Comment: What is the question? You have some code here which would not actually work because of syntax errors, but looks like it would be close if you fixed them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost OK.

```
n > 0
```

this will not make n positive, remove this line.
use instead:

```
abs(n)
```

if you need to invert it.. ex. if the value of n is -5, abs(n) will make it 5.

when you ask the user to put text, you are using your n value:

```
textPrint = input("Enter {}:".format(n))
```

the result of this will be that your function always prints "Enter 5:"... use instead:

```
textPrint = input("Enter {}/{}:".format(counter+1,n))
```

the result will be like "Enter 1/5:", "Enter 2/5:", ...

Then you use:

```
counter = n+1
```

This will only make your counter become larger than your while loop condition and exit your function prematurely, after entering just 1 line of text.
use instead:

```
counter += 1
```

Hope this puts you back on track :-)